# Flurry Analytics ANE and Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

I've compiled the Flurry Analytics ANE by StickSports with no problems, however when trying to package it through Flash Builder 4.6 the compilation process never ends.

Any tip on why it may be happening? For compiling the .ane file I used a Mac OS installation I had access, but I work under Windows 7. I know some extensions need access to the iOS SDK after being compiled, but this one doesn't seem to be one of them (or so I think).

Will try again on the Mac I used just in case.

Sorry for my lack of further details, but I don't know what else I can say about the issue. What can I do to help diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the extension makes the app to require Mac in order to be compiled. What a PITA, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my FlexBuilder hanging issue. First of all, ensure that you are using the latest Flex 4.6 SDK. If the problem still persists, whenever the IDE is hanging, go to terminal, type:

ps -Al |grep adt

Copy the command, kill the hanging build session. Go back to terminal.

cd wherever-bin-debug folder-of your-flex-mobile-project-is

Next paste the adt command you copied and hit enter.
You will now see the linking errors. Fix these errors. Once all is resolved, you can continue working in the IDE since FB only hangs on errors.

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Comment: I never had any problem compiling in Mac, but thanks for the tip. If I had any linking error I always got some alert, dunno. Also, if you are low in resources I always suggest compiling through adt directly, instead of using Flash Builder, the improvement is noticeable.